Apache Nifi Reading from CSV and querying to postgresql
I'm struggling a lot with this simple workflow and I can't make it work for me.
I have a CSV file where I have two columns ID and UUID. This is my document.
ID,UUID
0000317416,78f67ee6-293a-4373-8ed2-bdcbb21b3b2a
0004321903,1ce2327e-44b9-4611-b158-47af342ea8ed

So I'm reading CSVfile with GetFile and process with QueryRecord to get ID's on one side and UUID's on another.

The point now is to query to a PostgreSQL database to get all the records from this id.

So I linked flow id to ExecuteSQL,
And added a SQL select Query to get all the records,

SELECT * FROM alert WHERE pid = ${id}
But this query is not working.
This is the data provenance out of the query processor,

And this is the data provenance in of the executeSQL,

I think I'm missing some part here. I also tried with other processors like updateAttribute to try to get these id's but are always empty strings. Also I've reviewed several times the documentation where in this article is commented a very similar solution,  but still I couldn't make it work for me.
https://nifi.apache.org/docs/nifi-docs/components/org.apache.nifi/nifi-standard-nar/1.20.0/org.apache.nifi.processors.standard.QueryRecord/additionalDetails.html
Also, reviewed this one, Query Database Table with the values of csv in Apache NiFi
This is the error, since it looks like the id is empty.


It seems there's a misunderstanding here. While it's true that you can use QueryRecord for data transformations, the problem lies elsewhere. You are on the right track with your approach, but the error occurs in the ExecuteSQL processor.
According to the documentation, the declaration of the variable ${id} logically looks for an attribute id in the current flowfile. However, these IDs are part of the flowfile content, not attributes.
There are probably more efficient ways to handle this, but this is the method I would recommend (and the one I use).

The SplitJson processor should follow your QueryRecord processor. This will separate each record because we need each record to have the attribute corresponding to its ID. Additionally, this transforms the flowfile into JSON format, making it easier to extract the ID as an attribute.

Next, the EvaluateJsonPath processor creates a new attribute and extracts the value from the content of the flowfile.

And finally, you go back to your ExecuteSQL processor where you should have a query similar to this:
SELECT * FROM alert WHERE pid = ${csv.id}

Keep in mind that this isn't entirely efficient because you're going to make a database query for each record in your CSV. Ideally, you would create a process that leverages NiFi's strengths in handling large batches of data. However, if you only have a small number of records (around 3000), you can continue working this way.
I hope this helps! This is my first time answering questions after years of just reading them, haha.
Saludos desde Ecuador!
